# Titanium: Where is the SQLite DB Stored?

Tags: sqlite, titanium

I started a titanium app that uses a sqlite db. I'm getting strange DB results so just want to browse the database using FF SQLite Manager but I'm not sure where the database is?

This is the code that creates the db (part):

```
var db = (function() {

  //create an object which will be our public API
  var api = {};

  //maintain a database connection we can use
  var conn = Titanium.Database.open('quote');
```

I'm running Titanium studio on a Mac.

Thanks,

Billy

Comment: what platform are you on, that makes a difference... IOS/Android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i thought it was something like

```
/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/.../your.app.id/..
```

have a look. consider that there are two /Library-Folders (in root and in home). sorry for the unprecise answer.

Comment: What about on the phone itself (in the Personal directory or MyDocuments?

Answer (score 1):

All your projects folders are located here:

```
~/Library/Application\ Support/Titanium/appdata/
```

They are sorted by app ID.
In each folder you'll find a Databases.db file which contents your DBs if the app has one.

Answer (score 0):

`/data/data/your.app.id/databases/`

Comment: I don't have /data. tried cd /data but no directory found. Is this a subdirectory?

Comment: launch the adb shell that came with the android sdk `adb -e shell`

Answer (score 0):

For android , the location is /data/data/your.app.id/databases/

Ordinary, you could not direct see the file, unless you got the root permission。

And, you can use adb series command to get the file to you develop computer， and analyze the db file on you desktop computer.

For iOS, best way to see the db file is run the app in you simulater. the db file usually store at location simalar as this

```
/Users/[your name]/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/3CE12954-6C8A-48E1-BF71-CF483E01CBA1/Library/Private Documents
```

Answer (score 0):

The  path is at

> ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/{DEVICEID}/data/Containers/Data/Application/{APP_WEIRD_ID}/Library/Private
>   Documents/