# Appcelerator Titanium | Creating your first App

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I have started following [create your first titanium app](https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Creating_Your_First_Titanium_App) tutorial from the Appcelerator documentation.

Under **Initialize the book collection** section in **point number 4**, it says:

> 4. Add the book to the collection and persist it to the database.
>
>    `myBooks.add(book); 
>      book.save();`

and whole tutorial is working fine.

My question is, how/where can i see the values stored in database?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sql queries. Have a look at:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Database.ResultSet

there are some examples. You open it with `__alloy__`

```
var db = Ti.Database.open('_alloy_');
var rows = db.execute('SELECT * FROM books');
console.log('Row count: ' + rows.rowCount);
db.close();
```

you can also download the file and open it locally. There is another thread here [Titanium: Where is the SQLite DB Stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178931/titanium-where-is-the-sqlite-db-stored) to see where the db is stored